# task.continuewith vs dataflow in c#

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task, tpl-dataflow, dataflow

I have started learning [`TPL Dataflow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx). I'm trying hard to find the difference between `Task.ContinueWith` and dataflow. Below are the two samples codes which has the same objective. First is done with `Task.ContinueWith` and later with dataflow.
 Below is the example with `Task.ContinueWith`

```
var tk1 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Entered 1st Task");
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    return 2;
});

tk1.ContinueWith((t) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Entered 2nd Task");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
});

tk1.Wait();
```

and below is the same done with dataflow

```
var df1 = new TransformBlock<int,int>(t =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Entered 1st DF");
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    return 2;
});

var df2 = new ActionBlock<int>(t =>
{

    Console.WriteLine("Entered 2nd Task");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine(t);
});

df1.LinkTo(df2);

df1.Completion.ContinueWith(t =>
df2.Complete());

df1.Post(2);

df2.Completion.Wait();
```

`Task.ContinueWith` looks simple than the lengthy syntax which dataflow provides. Can anyone please clarify the difference between the two.

Answer (score 2):

Data flow i used to create a compleax proccesing pipleins, where the flow can branch and merge and loop. ( The example you are showing here is to simple)

Task.ContinueWith is used in a simpler code when the flow in just a list of function done one after another.

Answer (score 2):

With *your* code, there's actually no difference.

But you're doing it wrong for data flow - what's the use of a transform block, that only always ever produces one result independent of input?

Better do some processing...

```
var df1 = new TransformBlock<int,int>(input =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entered 1st DF");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        return input+1;
    });
```

... and then you see the difference:

`Task.Run` will just run once, but

```
df1.Post(2);
df1.Post(5);
df1.Post(27);
df1.Post(-1);
```

will all run through your data flow mesh and produce output.

And BTW: using `async`/`await` instead of `Task.ContinueWith` can make your code a lot simpler and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fully understand the basics for `TPL Dataflow`, as right now you trying to do things that can easily be done by `TPL Dataflow` pipeline itself:

```
df1.LinkTo(df2, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
```

Now you don't need to use `ContinueWith` for a `df1.Completion`, but you still need to notify the `df1` block (ugly naming, by the way) to (surprise) [complete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.idataflowblock.complete.aspx), as it doesn't know when to finish, comparing with task:

```
df1.Post(2);
df1.Complete();
```

Calling this method will deny all other messages sent to `df1` block, and after it's buffer became empty, it will propagate the completion down the pipeline, so you simply need to wait for it (either synchronously or asynchronously):

```
df2.Completion.Wait();
// or
await df2.Completion;
```

So, basically, the difference is that task can be run only once, comparing with block, which runs forever until you manually complete it. Note that you still can continue the [`Completion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.idataflowblock.completion.aspx) task for a block:

```
df2.Completion.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    // some other logic here
});
```